# Relationship field search not retriving posts in admin

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a site with 5000+ posts and a theme option page with a relationship field on it.
The infinite scroll and Taxonomy filter function of the relationship field works, but the search doesn't. Obviously with this many posts that's a deal breaker...

I can see it is making an ajax request via admin-ajax.php, but nothing is being returned. I have checked my error logs and there is nothing in there.

How do I diagnose / fix this? I'm guessing something is timing out? 
It runs ok in MAMP, but not my live server. I have tried modifying the php memory_limit, max_execution_time, and WP memory limits in wp-config.php. I've run out of ideas!

Comment: to fix it, look the ajax hook which is called and try to find where it stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is currently a conflict between Advanced Custom Fields Pro (5.2.8) and Relevanssi Premium (1.13.3) plugins.

If you enable the 'Use search in admin' function in Relevanssi then the problem described above appears. ACF support put the 'blame' in the Relevanssi plugin. I'm awaiting a reply from the developer if there is a work-around or solution. For now I have disabled Relevanssi search in the admin area and ACf now works as expected.